# eAccelerator php eaccelerator_put

Tags: php, caching, eaccelerator

i've got shared hosting with eAccelerator

```
> eAccelerator
> 
> eAccelerator support  enabled
> Version   0.9.6.1 Caching Enabled true
> Optimizer Enabled true Check mtime
> Enabled   true Memory Size    536,870,840
> Bytes Memory Available    365,415,144
> Bytes Memory Allocated    171,455,696
> Bytes Cached Scripts  1649 Removed
> Scripts   0
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> eaccelerator.allowed_admin_path   no
> value no value
> eaccelerator.cache_dir    /tmp/eaccelerator   /tmp/eaccelerator
> eaccelerator.check_mtime  1   1
> eaccelerator.debug    0   0
> eaccelerator.enable   1   1
> eaccelerator.filter   no value    no value
> eaccelerator.log_file no value    no
> value eaccelerator.optimizer  1   1
> eaccelerator.shm_max  0   0
> eaccelerator.shm_only 1   1
> eaccelerator.shm_prune_period 0   0
> eaccelerator.shm_size 512 512
> eaccelerator.shm_ttl  0   0
```

but when i try to use api `eaccelerator_put('zz', time());` i get error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function eaccelerator_put()`

what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shared memory is disabled in eAccelerator by default. You have to specifically compile it using the `--with-eaccelerator-shared-memory` flag. You may check which functions are enabled in eAccelerator using this code snippet:

```
<?php
print_r(get_extension_funcs('eaccelerator'));
?>
```